# How to output DOMDocuments?

Tags: php, dom

Maybe I am missing something... but the DOM Object is empty in this code:

```
$input = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($input); //supress errors on invalid html!
var_dump($doc);
die();
```

I really don't know what could be wrong with that code. I have verified that $input is actually filled with the html contents of the web page.

The output is:
    object(DOMDocument)#3 (0) { }

I don't understand why...

Comment: I get a lot of errors because of the invalid html. I need to supress them. Btw, var_dump(@$doc->loadHTML($input)) is "true".

Comment: Static invocation of loadHTML does not work, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. To see the HTML, use [`DOMDocument::saveHTML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.savehtml) (or [`saveXML()`](http://php.net/domdocument.savexml)).

Comment: Thanks, I see you are right. So why can't I view the dom document object's contents? Is shows the behavior of a resource?

Comment: Thank you for this. You just saved a co-worker a lot of time trying to figure out why the object was empty.

Answer (score 2):

> The output is: object(DOMDocument)#3 (0) { }

Yes. That's what a `var_dump`ed `DOMDocument` looks like.

If you want to look at the HTML representation of the content *inside* the document, `saveHTML()` on it. That spits out a cleaned up version of the HTML on Google's home page for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$input = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$test=@$doc->loadHTML($input); //supress errors on invalid html!
var_dump($test);
die();
//output
//bool(true)
?>
```

or try

```
$input = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');

$buffer = ob_get_clean();
$tidy = new tidy();
$input = $tidy->repairString($input);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($input); //supress errors on invalid html!
var_dump($doc);
die();
```

Comment: If you add "var_dump($doc);" to your code, you'll see that $doc is still an empty object. At least it is for me!

Comment: The error supression is not the problem. The php manual specifically states that a string can be loaded even it is not valid.